# How to add jsonarray into dictionary

Tags: json, dictionary, token

How to add list of object into dictionary as json array?
my code is:

```
public override Task TokenEndpoint(OAuthTokenEndpointContext context)
    {
        var role = new UserAccount().GetUserRolesList(context.Identity.Name);

        context.AdditionalResponseParameters.Add("userName",context.Identity.Name);

        var jsonRole = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(role.Select(x => new {x.RoleId,x.Title}),Formatting.None);

        context.AdditionalResponseParameters.Add("roles",jsonRole);
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> property in context.Properties.Dictionary)
        {
            context.AdditionalResponseParameters.Add(property.Key, property.Value);
        }
        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }
```

I want to add roles list as json array but add into dictionary as string.

Comment: What isn't working? What specific part are you struggling with? Are you having any errors? Show what you're tried already.

Comment: result is:

"roles": "[{\"RoleId\":1,\"Title\":\"admin\"},{\"RoleId\":2,\"Title\":\"user\"}]"

but I want json array like:

"roles": [{"RoleId":1,"Title":"admin"},{"RoleId":2,"Title":"user"}]

Comment: Did you figure out how to do this ?